# SharePoint Calendar Scheduled events

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

When I create a scheduled event on SharePoint Calendar it shows up as an event on everyone's calendar.

How do I get it to only show on the Attendees Calendar?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering calendar list view based on Attendees column using `[Me]` like below:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use filtering to modify a SharePoint list view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224#OfficeVersion=2010-2019)